# using map in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary

```
const practiceData = [[14, 21, 23, 64], [33, 46, 51, 65]]
function one(x) {
    for (i = 0; i <= practiceData.length; i++) {

        return x + 1
    }
}

const out = practiceData.map(one);

console.log(out)
```

[ '14,21,23,641', '33,46,51,651' ]
this is the output every element is not increasing by +1 instead it is adding +1 at last of each element

```
const practiceData = [[14, 21, 23, 64], [33, 46, 51, 65]]
function one(x) {
    for (i = 0; i <= practiceData.length; i++) {

        return x + 1
    }
}

const out = practiceData.map(one);

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please start your question by describing what are you exactly trying to do with the provided piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code?

```
const practiceData = [[14, 21, 23, 64], [33, 46, 51, 65]];
const out = practiceData.map(items=>items.map(item=>item+1));
console.log(out);
```

Comment: thanx it works i am a begineer sorry to ask but how do we use map inside map i want to learn more about higher order functions can you suggest some source